# C - Practice -Structs and Function - input error

Tags: c, function, input, struct, nested

I'm practicing C using structs and functions. When I ask the user to input the information about book, the code runs well till I ask to input the publisher name, here I'm always getting return EXIT_FAILURE no matther what is the input. I think that I'm doing some error the way I write the variable in the `scanf` because is a struct inside another struct and I still don't get this matter perfectly.

Bellow the code (it isn't complete):

```
#define MAXB 2
#define MAXSTR 100

typedef struct date // publication date
{
 int day, month, year;   
    
}DATE;

typedef struct authors
{
    char authorName[MAXSTR];
    char authorwebp[MAXSTR];
    DATE birthDate;
}AUTHOR;

typedef struct publishers
{
    char publisherName[MAXSTR];
    char publishAddress[MAXSTR];
}PUBLISHER;

typedef struct books
{
    char title[MAXSTR];
    char type[MAXSTR];
    PUBLISHER publisher;
    AUTHOR author[5];
    DATE publishDate;
}BOOK;

void add_book( BOOK *b )
{
if (scanf(" %[^\n]s", b->publisher.publisherName) !=1);  // always getting EXIT_FAILURE
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
int main()
{
    BOOK b[MAXB];
    add_book(b);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: remove the semicolon in the if statement, also a void function should never be able to return EXIT_FAILURE

Comment: In the line `(scanf(" %[^\n]s" ...  !=1);` you have a `;`, that is why you are always returning `EXIT_FAILURE`, remove that and check if the code does what you expect.

Comment: It's working, thank you all.

Comment: @Luke_  should I change the function to int?

Comment: @LuísOliveira yes, EXIT_FAILURE expands to 1 while EXIT_SUCCESS expands to 0

Comment: So, in cases of fuction that I want to do a procedure, like ask an input and get an output, if I 'm using an error mensagem, the function should always be int?

Answer (score 1):

"if (scanf(" %[^\n]s", b->publisher.publisherName) !=1); <-remove the semicolon "

Question answered by @ser3121023, @Luke_ and @Alejandro Montilla.